# Continue a curve from pre-built shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, bezier-curve

Take this image for example:

[image]

How would you tackle the task of continuing the curve (left shape) till it joins with the second shape in a 'more precise' way than taking the pen and ***guessing*** the angle/curvature?

---

I usually end up redrawing from the last straight anchor points:

[image]

Comment: Its possible to extend a bezier curve, now i only have t-param  extension would be better to extend by length parametrisized bezier domain, but i dont have a clue on how to do that so... you can find more on the subject in [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84741/create-new-layer-by-extending-length-of-existing-arc/84838#84838). It might work well or not (but that's normal, right). **IMPORTANT**: copy the bezier segment to extend! PS: let me knw if thsi could be an answer for you

Comment: @joojaa I ran fast over it and it looks nice, will go through it in about 30 minutes and get back to you! Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

Here's one method that might work for you if you have Illustrator CC.

Use the Curvature Tool.

[image: Use of the curvature tool screen capture]

The result looks pretty smooth, and done without the need to mess with Bezier curve handles!

[image: Finished result]

The Curvature Tool is a fairly new feature, Illustrator CC October 2014 release, and later.

Comment: Hey, yeah, this works nicely but I don't have CC. My version is CS 5.5 Extended therefore I don't have this feature. Probably should've mentioned the software version but +1 for a nice feature that will benefit other readers that have CC. :D

Comment: @Alin Ok, so perhaps it would help if you created a couple of bezier paths and turn these into guides before you attempt the edit. See example here http://imgur.com/aOOYTki guides are highlighted red, That would certainly take some of the guesswork out of it.